# Manipulating Mongoose/MongoDB Array using Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've noticed there's little documentation and info about how I should manipulate an array of objects using Mongoosejs.

I have the following model/Schema for an User:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module Dependencies
 */

var bcrypt    = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var crypto    = require('crypto');
var mongoose  = require('mongoose');

 /**
 * Custom types
 */
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  email: { type: String, unique: true, index: true },
  password: { type: String },
  type: { type: String, default: 'user' },
  facebook: { type: String, unique: true, sparse: true },
  twitter: { type: String, unique: true, sparse: true },
  google: { type: String, unique: true, sparse: true },
  github: { type: String, unique: true, sparse: true },
  tokens: Array,

  profile: {
    name: { type: String, default: '' },
    gender: { type: String, default: '' },
    location: { type: String, default: '' },
    website: { type: String, default: '' },
    picture: { type: String, default: '' },
    phone: {
      work: { type: String, default: '' },
      home: { type: String, default: '' },
      mobile: { type: String, default: '' }
    }
  },

  activity: {
    date_established: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    last_logon: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    last_updated: { type: Date }
  },

  resetPasswordToken: { type: String },
  resetPasswordExpires: { type: Date },

  verified: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  verifyToken: { type: String },

  enhancedSecurity: {
    enabled: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    type: { type: String },  // sms or totp
    token: { type: String },
    period: { type: Number },
    sms: { type: String },
    smsExpires: { type: Date }
  },

  friends: [{
    friend: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    verified: { type: Boolean, default: false }
  }]

});

/* (...) some functions that aren't necessary to be shown here */

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

So as you can check I defined Friends inside User like this:

```
  friends: [{
    friend: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    verified: { type: Boolean, default: false }
  }]
```

Now the question is how can I add, edit and delete this array in a Node.js script?

***BOTTOMLINE:*** How can I manipulate arrays that are inside MongoDB Schemas, using Node.js and Mongoose.js? Do I always have to create a Schema function or can I access it directly?

***EDIT (13/07/2014):*** So far I've created a HTTP GET that gives me the array like this:

```
app.get('/workspace/friends/:userid', passportConf.isAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
  User.find({_id: req.params.userid}, function (err, items) {
      if (err) {
          return (err, null);
      }
      console.log(items[0].friends);
      res.json(items[0].friends);
  });
});
```

But this only returns an array of friendIds, but what if I want to create some sort of '/workspace/friends/:userid/del/:friendid' POST, or add POST. I can't seem to figure out how I can get this done.

Comment: You do so as with regular JavaScript objects (`push`, `concat`, etc).  What have you tried that's not working?

Comment: Hey @aarosil I made a GET request for the array but how can I edit and save it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like following

```
app.get('/workspace/friends/:userid/delete/:friendId', passportConf.isAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
  User.findOne({_id: req.params.userid}, function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
          return (err, null);
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < user.friends.length; i++) {
        if (user.friends[i]._id === req.params.friendId) {
            user.friends = user.friends.splice(i,1)
        }
      }
      user.save(function(err, user, numAffected){
        if (!err )res.json(user)
        res.send('error, couldn\'t save: %s', err)
      })
  });
});
```

What it says in mongoose [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) is that

"The callback will receive three parameters, err if an error occurred, [model] which is the saved [model], and numberAffected which will be 1 when the document was found and updated in the database, otherwise 0.

The fn callback is optional. If no fn is passed and validation fails, the validation error will be emitted on the connection used to create this model."

Comment: How is this saving the edit? That's what I don't get? Doesn't the save function need a return or something? And for adding I could use what? Verify if exists user.friends.push(...)? and simply save it with user.save?

Comment: That's correct, the mongoDB stuff is handled behind scenes when you call save(), the instance of the model will handle appropriately.  There is saveral ways to save, check out [doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html), it's thorough.  Also check out the [Schema.Types.Mixed](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html), it's a wild free for all!

Comment: But what do I save the argument from the anonymous function?

Comment: Isn't working... I corrected some minor errors like missing semicolons but it's not working. It's for some reason not entering the if statement to remove the friend connection. Do you have a clue about this?

Comment: check that req.params.friendID is coming up as what you expect.

Comment: it is.. I printed both req.params.friendId and user.friends[i].friendId (the real parametre) and they give exact the same string but don't enter the if statement...

Comment: Are you sure not entering the `if`? Can you change in `if` to `user.friends = user.friends.splice..` and check again?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I've added a console.log('User found'); to check and it doesn't come up... I see the logs from the loop but in the if statement itself I get nothing...

Comment: OK, try posting the new code, hard to say what's wrong just from the description

Comment: It works with an 2 x equal comparison, so it seems the type is different and 3 x equal in the if statement returns false.

Comment: did you assign the user to the result of splice operation?  I edited answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57350/discussion-between-aarosil-and-cmpsoares).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manipulate arrays, you should convert these in objects before.

```
User.findOne({_id: req.params.userid}, function (err, user) {
  if (err) {
      return (err, null);
  }

  var user = user.toObject();

  //... your code, an example =>
  delete user.friends;
  res.json(user);
});
```

Regards, Nicholls